# How can I call a method on an element in a nested OrderedDictionary by index

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am using a nested ordered dictionary called toolSystem to store tools into categories and subtypes. The toolSystem.add is adding the categories and the gardeningTools.Add are adding the subtypes for that categorie (eg toolSystem has the categorie gardeningTools and a subtype of lineTrimer which is array of tools class).

```
OrderedDictionary toolSystem = new OrderedDictionary();
OrderedDictionary gardeningTools = new OrderedDictionary();
ToolCollection lineTrimmers = new ToolCollection(0);
Tool newTool = new Tool("Hose", 1, 1);

toolSystem.Add("Gardening Tools", gardeningTools);
gardeningTools.Add("Line Trimmers", lineTrimmers);
```

`ToolSystem` has a method called `add` that has this signature:

```
public void add(Tool tool);
```

The problem I am having is that I need to add a new `Tool` instance to the `lineTrimmers` dictionary but my method scope only has access to the `toolSystem` dictinary, so I can't use the `lineTrimmers` reference directly.

Is there anyway to use add by index. eg `toolSystem[0][0].add(newTool);`?

---

I have tried to use this:

```
toolSystem["Gardening Tools"]["Line Trimmers"].Add(newTool);
```

But that resulted in the following error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `toolSystem["Gardening Tools"].Add("xx", xx);` ?

Comment: You can do `toolSystem["Gardening Tools"]["Line Trimmers"].Add(...)`. But this seems like a database would be a better option than lots of nested dictionaries.

Comment: Yeah not sure why that dosent work i get this error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Well what is the type of `lineTrimmers` then?

Comment: Alternatively to explicitly constructing all these categories, you could create a Category reference property on your entities, add them all to a single collection then use LINQ to dynamically build your category collections.

Comment: `private ToolCollection lineTrimmers = new ToolCollection(0);` ToolCollection uses a array to hold items from the tool class. I would use databases but that is out of spec for this assignment

Comment: OK, so what is `ToolCollection`? Please, please, please give us useful information and don't drip feed it to us.

Comment: `ToolCollection` must not have a definition for `.Add()`, hence the error.

Comment: I have posted ToolCollection, it is a bit out of data atm

Comment: So the method is named `add` not `Add`...

Comment: When i try and do `toolSystem[][]` i get this error as well `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: Using add seems to work but the above error is where it is stuck atm

Comment: Please provide a [mre], you just keep giving snippets of information that are completely useless without the wider context.

Comment: Will do that now

Comment: What benefit does `ToolCollection` class give over just using an in-built collection? You can't apply the `[]` indexer keyword without defining it in your class.

Comment: Unfortunately for this assignment we have been limited to using the class structure they have given us. We are not allowed to make any changes to the provided classes. I have also uploaded the minimal example

Comment: Why did you create the `location int[]` that serves zero purpose, it really complicates your example. Which tool system and categorie do you want to add the tool to? Those variables should be promoted to arguments of the `Add` method

Comment: The `location int[]` is just a placeholder for //Calls method. The method it calls is `SelectCategories()` which uses the console to print all the options in toolsystem so they can select where they want to add the tool. Unfortunately i am not allowed to change the `Add` method. Thats why i am calling the method. In the exampe code i want to place the hose in toolSystem in the categorie gardeningTools in the subtype lineTrimmers or `toolSystem[categorie eg 0][subtype eg 0].add(tool)`

Comment: You can use the syntax you are asking, except you will have to cast the child collection, I think for your assignment you are not supposed to try to do it in 1 line, can be done, but in the real world you would use different structures for this type of logic. Just get access each child item individually.

Comment: This is probably not going to help the community, I'll watch for it to re-open, until then just use this: `((toolSystem[location[0]] as OrderedDictionary)[location[1]] as ToolCollection).add(tool);`

Comment: Thank you so much i have been stuck on this for half of today. Is there any way i can change the question to make it more general and usable by the community?

Comment: I don't think so, not without reposting something else almost entirely. You provided too much background info that complicates things for us. What you really wanted to know was "How can I call a method on an element in a nested OrderedDictionary by index?" The only setup for this would be the data and your line after "this is what I'm trying to get working". You would also include the actual error message. I'd do it myself but they frown on edits that totally alter your content, it make all previous comments invalid. Ask a new question if you want

Comment: Done my best, do you see what I mean now, about how the rest of the information you posted really didn't constitute _minimal_

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you for that and showing me the way of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your attempt to use the strings to access the elements in the dictionaries, with typed collections this sort of syntax will work, but the issue is that the `OrderedDictionary` is *untyped*, so the value of the elements is typed as an `Object` so you will need to cast it in order to use the specific indexer logic:

The following is a simple attempt that explicitly casts the individual elements to the types that we *assume* that they are:

```
OrderedDictionary gardeningTools = (OrderedDictionary)toolSystem["Gardening Tools"];
ToolCollection lineTrimmers = (ToolCollection)gardeningTools["Line Trimmers"];
lineTrimmers.Add(newTool);
```

You could execute this as a single line:

```
(((OrderedDictionary)toolSystem["Gardening Tools"])["Line Trimmers"] as ToolCollection).Add(newTool);
```

> **[OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-5.0)**
> There are two indexers you can use to address the items in the dictionary directly, the example above is using the `Object` typed indexer, you could have used the integer indexer in the same way,
>
> - [Item[Int32]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Specialized_OrderedDictionary_Item_System_Int32_)   *returns `Object`*
>   Gets or sets the value at the specified index.
> - [Item[Object]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Specialized_OrderedDictionary_Item_System_Object_)  *returns `Object`*
>   Gets or sets the value with the specified key.

In many cases where we use the object typed collections we do so because we *want* to vary the type of each individual element, if the elements were all of the same type we would usually use a *Generic* or strongly typed collection.

We should avoid getting in the habit of explicitly casting values as it will throw exceptions at runtime, we can now use [Type test pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests) to check for a specific type and optimistically cast the value in the same expression:

```
if (toolSystem["Gardening Tools"] is OrderedDictionary gardeningTools)
{
    if (gardeningTools["Line Trimmers"] is ToolCollection lineTrimmers)
    {
        lineTrimmers.Add(newTool);
    }
}
```

This can still be simplified into almost one line:

```
if (toolSystem["Gardening Tools"] is OrderedDictionary gardeningTools
    && gardeningTools["Line Trimmers"] is ToolCollection lineTrimmers)
        lineTrimmers.Add(newTool);
```

If you know the indexes of the elements, you can use them too:

```
int categorieIndex = 0;
int subTypeIndex = 0;

if (toolSystem[categorieIndex] is OrderedDictionary categorie
    && categorie[subTypeIndex] is ToolCollection subType)
        subType.Add(newTool);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the explanation and how to avoid runtime errors it will help me alot